# Can 250V mains damage my 100-240V devices?

Tags: electrical

Until today, I thought the European electricity network was 230 ± 6%. I measured my supply as 250V, which surprised me as that's 6V above 244V.

I checked, and [the specification is actually 230 +10% / -6%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity#Voltage_levels) (so my supply is below the 253V maximum).

However, many of my devices (Laptop Charger, iMac, Phone charger, etc) have a range of 100-240V written on the transformer.

Is any damage to these devices possible?

Comment: The listed voltages are nominal. The devices should handle anything within the spec range you mentioned. Variation in line voltage is common almost everywhere.

Comment: @Tim that quote to isherwood - huh?  Typically electronic devices are made for dual voltage operation and you will note many auto switch. The devices are intended to operate across continents utilizing kit of adapters (I am talking plugs) as Manufacturers do not need to make different devices for different markets just because the power systems are different- one size fits all. Economy of Scale. Are you measuring correctly RMS? (UK +10% = 276VAC at that I would be wary) but 240v devices still work there. 250/20 = 12.5V , 250/13 =19V https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country

Comment: @Ken UK has been *nominally* 230V for years.  In most cases no changes were needed as 240V is within tolerance. Also continuous input is becoming much more common than auto-switching, especially for low powers.  The stated range is 100-240, not 100-120 and 220-240 so these devices (unless printed with lies) have a continuous input range

Comment: the devices you mention all have enough on-board "smarts" to handle the extra ~5%. Some naive appliances, like blenders, fans, vacuums, etc, could _slightly_ overheat on long run times, _possibly_ reducing service life, but only if over-used, for example using a cheap consumer vacuum to clean an entire hotel wing.

Comment: @ChrisH provide me a link for 'continuous mode power supply'. I am referring to switched mode power supplies often referred to as switching power supplies. They regulate the output voltage/current appropriately. However there are limits on inputs and +10% is 276V in the UK - in the US that is industrial lighting voltage (277V). My comment on the ratio division is to show the result of a non-regulated supply is not out of tolerance for DC devices (< 2V). The op will be fine with his devices, but I would be wary at the top end tolerance of 276V.

Comment: @Ken where is this 276V calculated from?

Comment: Mains is either 100-120 or 200-250 anything outside that will be abnormal. So regardless of regulation range you should not have 160VAC input.  The rectifier circuit can be configured as a voltage doubler by the addition of a switch operated either manually or automatically. This feature permits operation from power sources that are normally at 115 V or at 230 V.  Further SMPS now sense input voltage rather than output because it is cheaper and more efficient. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply

Comment: @Tim - I am sorry my mistake - for some reason I doubled the 10% tolerance don't know why I did that - lack of sleep on my end - maybe I was thinking 250 for some reason. My bad. I should double check my stuff when I am tired..

Comment: @Ken I'm also referring to SMPSs, but with a continuous input voltage range, at least according to their specs, and when I've worked on small ones recently there's been no switching circuit on the input side

Comment: @ChrisH there is a switching circuit it is just auto-switching - you don't need to touch anything. Older units had a manual switch - newer units sense the input voltage and do the switch auto-magically , once they sense input voltage they then regulate - duty cycles on/off to control the voltage and the current. They are labeled 100-240 (you are correct). no-one has 160VAC so 100-130/200-250 is acceptable saying. I am not sure how the input works if large over voltage is supplied such as 260VAC and ^. Internally  capacitor 250VAC is very standard / inductors probably rated higher.

Comment: Claiming a single range when there are two is a lie, and if you think you never see 160V you've never been to India or Africa,where brownouts are common. If you're saying that the main switching transistor Street an input stage of diodes and capacitors can handle both those ranges but not in between I'd like to know how. If you're saying there's another component to change the input configuration like manual switches used to, I'll repeat: not in the last couple I've repaired. The tracks are easy enough to follow, @Ken

Comment: @ChrisH - you are debating semantics. The world uses power 100-130V, 200-240V. 160V is not used as nominal mains voltage anywhere in the world - name one country. Brown outs occur in lots of places but manufacturers do not post specifications on brown out voltage of x or y, the nominal's are used in specs. The sense circuit on input senses the voltage and adjusts the duty cycle to achieve the desired output regulation (this is how a SMPS auto-switches between 100ish and 200ish without a manual switch).

Comment: @Ken I'm describing reality. Of course it adjusts the duty cycle, that's how SMPSs work. They need to adjust over a fairly wide range to respond to changes in load, so they don't just switch at one duty cycle for 120 and another for 220.. I might post a link to a product with a detailed spec sheet, but apart from that I'm out of here

Comment: @Ken specs as promised, from a reputable manufacturer I've used in the past: [Products designed for world-wide operation have a universal input range typically covering 90–264VAC. Conventionally a product with universal input is expected to offer its full power rating across this input range with some products offering a de-rated output for lower input voltages down to 85 or 80VAC to cover operation in areas where the AC supply is prone to brownout](https://www.xppower.com/Portals/0/brochures/Essential_Guide_to_Power_Supplies.pdf) indicates continuous range (see fig near that quote)

Comment: @ChrisH Again you are arguing semantics - it does not matter if it says 100-240V it works 100-130V and it also works 200-240V if you have a mains in that range it works, no one cares if it works at 160VAc they aren't shopping for one that works at 160VAC. They are SMPS's they don't spec brown out voltages - they spec what a consumer can understand and either will work in the same scenarios the op desires. I am not going to debate semantics let it go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You'll be fine

The voltage rating on mains devices and components is a *nominal* rating -- tolerances on the mains voltage need not be taken into account here, as it is understood by equipment designers and rating agencies that mains voltages vary slightly for a given nominal voltage.

Answer (score 0):

These devices you mention will be fine. Devices that utilize a direct power transition such as a clothes washer or dishwasher where the AC motor is or you have specific requirements is different.

Your devices utilize what is known as Switching Power Supplies or Switched-Mode power supplies SMPS. They are auto-switching for voltage and auto-regulate. The newest items have an input voltage sensing system as that is a cheaper and more efficient means to regulate than output sensing, however which ever internal sensing technology they use - they work across the globe.

See the below information for more details:

[Switched-mode power supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply)

Comment: Most of the universal switching type power supplies run fine at 100v up to just over 300v.  + for isherwood & 3phase.